# Accessing Salesforce CPQ Setting Properties In Apex

Tags: cpq, cpq-plugins, cpq-api

In Salesforce CPQ settings configuration page, there are some settings which are used to created records during the quoting process. For example the "Subscription Term Unit" is used to indicate whether the quote terms in days or months. Possible values are - Month & Day. Is there any way to access this values in the quote programmatically in Apex? We want to do some customization based on this value, so wanted to get some help on how to identify this value in program.

Attached is a screenshot for reference.

Thanks,
Bikram.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to access protected settings of managed package programatically. These are global setting so you need to take it under consideration if you really need them for further implementation process. I would encourage you to also check the possibilities of [CPQ Plugins](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.cpq_api_dev.meta/cpq_api_dev/cpq_plugins_parent.htm) once custom logic is required

Comment: Any idea how to find out the subscription term type from the quote object? We have only "Subscription Term" which will store values like 12. How do we know if the user specified number is in months or in days? I think there should be some way to determine it.

Comment: That's why you have a package settings that are applied global. If your selection equals to Month all quotes subscription term unit will be in months. There is no option to have both month and day - you need to decide based on the company business what's a better approach